# Adding syntax highlighting to programming languages in Xcode 4.0

Tags: xcode4, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know if it's possible to add custom syntax highlighting to Xcode 4?

In Xcode 3 you just had to add some files in:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Specifications/

but that does not seem to work anymore?

Comment: Tried modifying files in /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework and /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework. Anyone had any progress with this? Using Xcode 4.0.2.

Comment: I would like to know about that too. So far the mantra seems to be that Xcode 4 doesn't support it, not even with hacking.

Comment: I'd also be interested in using existing syntax coloring schemes for other file extensions (specifically JavaScript coloring for .jsm files). If there were a way to set the default tabstop on a per-filetype basis that would be even better.

Comment: Do you have solution for XCode5.0.2?

Answer (score 6):

XCode syntax coloring for lua https://github.com/bastos/lua-xcode-coloring

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that, but I think it's worth trying the following (at least on XCode 4.3):

1 - Go to /Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ inside the XCode package;

2 - Find the files "Built-in file types.pbfilespec" and "Standard file types.pbfilespec";

3 - Create backup copies of those files;

4 - The language syntax should be inserted in the file "Built-in file types.pbfilespec". Just take the definition of C language, for instance, as a template and define the new language syntax;

5 - The file "Standard file types.pbfilespec" seems to make reference to the file "Built-in file types.pbfilespec", but that's just a guess. If step 4 is not enough, consider editing this file too;

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried adding the .jsm extension to Standard file types.pbfilespec inside the sourcecode.javascript section but it still doesn't use the JS syntax coloring for those files. I figured maybe I had to set up a UTI for those files so I added it to the exported UTIs in the XCode Info.plist (copied the json definition and changed the extension to .jsm and the MIME type to text/javascript). Still no dice. I noticed that the "Kind" for .js files in Get Info is listed as "JavaScript" but I don't know how to make that the Kind for .jsm as well (right now it's "XCode Document").

Comment: It seems that those files appear many times inside the DevToolsCore.framework. I'll try to change the files in /Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/ and see if it works.

Comment: I just found this source that may help us: [http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-plugin-interface/](http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-plugin-interface/), specially topic 3 (Specification Files).

Comment: Yeah that doc's been around forever but unfortunately it only seems to apply to XCode 3.

Comment: Beside "Built-in file types.pbfilespec" and "Standard file types.pbfilespec", there's also the OtherFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/Resources and SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework folders (Xcode 4.4 bundle) that contain xclangspec files, so one could create new files there. However, I fear this is all useless because there's also a signature file at  OtherFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature/CodeResources which contains a hash (of some sort) for every language. So unless we find out how those hashes are generated, I don't think this can work.

Answer (score -1):

Version 4 uses .dvtcolortheme files and they should be placed into  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes

Solarized has a nice and small tutorial:
https://github.com/brianmichel/solarized/tree/master/apple-xcode4-solarized

Comment: Note: This only changes the color scheme. It does not let one define new syntax-highlighting schemes for programming languages not already recognized by Xcode.