# How can I assign a syntax coloring to a file type in Xcode 4?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding syntax highlighting to programming languages in Xcode 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269994/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-programming-languages-in-xcode-4-0)

I know I can change the syntax highlighting on a per-file basis from the *Editor: Syntax Coloring* menu.

But how can I set a default for a file type? (I want Ruby highlighting for all my .rspec and .haml files, for example.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "Adding syntax highlighting to programming languages in Xcode 4.0." That question is about getting syntax highlighting for a new language. This one is about making an existing syntax highlighting encompass additional files based on extensions Xcode is not automatically identifying correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot set a per file color scheme.

Comment: Even a simple google search shows this is incorrect.